# What is the purpose of the LibraryLoader.LoadLibrary function in Python ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

Using Python ctypes, we can get an instance of a C shared library (e.g. standard math) in two ways that have the same effect:

```py
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library
libm1 = ctypes.CDLL(find_library('m'))
libm2 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library('m'))
```

The references libm1 and libm2 are distinct (`libm1 is libm2` => `False`) but appear equivalent in all other ways. In fact, the rather simple implementation makes these 2 calls equivalent:

```py
class LibraryLoader(object):
    def __init__(self, dlltype):
        self._dlltype = dlltype

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name[0] == '_':
            raise AttributeError(name)
        dll = self._dlltype(name)
        setattr(self, name, dll)
        return dll

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return getattr(self, name)

    def LoadLibrary(self, name):
        return self._dlltype(name)

cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)
```

From the code, we can see that by causing `__getattr__` to be called, we can utilize a caching mechanism. Indeed, the following code will also get you a reference to libm.so:

```py
libm3 = ctypes.cdll[find_library('m')]
```

As per the documentation, this will return the same reference to libm on subsequent calls. However, this is almost never done in code examples -- I assume because it feels clunky / non-idiomatic. But `LoadLibrary` skips the caching mechanism and always returns a new instance of the library.

So what is the intended purpose for the `LibraryLoader` class, and particularly the `LoadLibrary` function?

Comment: This class is not generally useful, and the global `cdll` and `windll` instances of it should be avoided. Caching `CDLL` and `WinDLL` instances is a disaster for libraries that use the same shared libraries, which is especially a problem for libc and the Windows API.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks, I'll keep that advice in mind. I had a feeling that might be true, and you can always "cache" an instance at the module/script level; you should usually wrap the calls in a module, anyway. I'll leave the question up in case someone has a good answer for why it exists in the first place.

Comment: ctypes was developed on Windows. It's common for DLLs to have names that are legal Python identifiers. So you'll see code like `cdll.msvcrt` and `windll.kernel32`. This is a bad idea because these `CDLL` and `WinDLL` instances cache function pointers. Setting the `restype`, `argtypes`, and `errcheck` attributes affects every user of the cached library. Also, for `libc` we want the `CDLL` option `use_errno` with `ctypes.get_errno` and `ctypes.set_errno`. For Windows we want the `WinDLL` option `use_last_error` with `ctypes.get_last_error` and `ctypes.set_last_error`.